# Submit form while executing onclick event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with a button. When users click on it, there is an onclick event written in javascript function. At the same time, I would like to record the form values onto a text file on the server. This is being done by a php piece of code. Here is my dilemma:

If the type is set as "Button", the onclick event works fine but the form values are not taken to the php code. If the type is set as "Submit", the php code works well but the onclick event is overtaken.

My question is: is there a simple solution to work around? Thank you.

Update: Thank you all for your kind help here. So far I haven't been able to find a solution yet. The problem is that once the submit function for form is in, the iframe content won't load. Here are the key codes.

```
/**** index.php:  ****/
<form id="form1" name= "form1" method="post" >
<center>
<table>
<tr>
<td><b><p id="zip_code">Enter Zip Code:</p></b></td>
<td><input id="zipcode" name="zipcode" placeholder="12345" type="text" /></td>
</tr>

</table>
</center>
<input value="Check Inventory" onclick="getwebURL()" type="button" /> 
</form>

/** the onclick event will update the iframe contents **/
<iframe id="myFrame2" src="" name="myFrame2" height="1026" width="100%"></iframe>
/** php code that will record user inputs with time stamp **/
<?php
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
// Get the zip code they entered in the form
$zipcode = $_POST['zipcode'];
// We want the file to be a text file right?
$ex = "record.txt";
// Try to open a file named $file$ex (johndoe.txt for example)
// Because this file doesn't exist yet the server creates it
$write = fopen("$ex","a");
// Now open the file up again but this time save the email in it
$savestring = $zipcode . "," . date("c") . "," . "\n";
fwrite($write,$savestring);
// MAKE SURE you close the file!!!
fclose($write);
?>

/**** Javascript that has getwebURL() function ****/
function getwebURL()
{
     document.getElementById('myFrame2').src='http://www.example.com?zipCode='+document.getElementById('zipcode').value;
}
```

Update2: After reading around, it seems my best bet is to keep it as TYPE "Button" and inside the onclick event, using AJAX call php code. Anybody have such an example, in particularly how to pass the parameter around. Thanks.

Update3: Used AJAX call php code and problem solved. Thank you everyone for your kind help.

Comment: i would suggest to show code...

Comment: "is there a simple solution to work around?" Ya, certainly... GL

Answer (score 0):

Try having the type as `button` then in your function add the code blow

`$('#myid').submit();`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Please see the sample code. When I submit, the iframe content does not refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the submit event instead of the click event on the submit button.

```
$("#submitbutton").submit(function(){
  $.post("ajax/writestufftofile.php", data ...); // Send data to php script to write to file
});
```

Something like the above code will listen to the submit event, when its fired, it will send an ajax call to the webserver and still submit the form.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Thanks,

Comment: Thank you for your help. Since the iframe needs to be shown, so submit() will refresh and likely not trigger refreshing iframe. Problem solved indeed by using AJAX call php code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button').click(function() {
 $('#formId').submit();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Please see the sample code. When I submit, the iframe content does not refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `onclick` event, but the form's `onsubmit` event instead.

```
<form onsubmit="return my_js_function();">
    <!-- your form -->
</form>
```

The `onsubmit` event is triggered when the form is being submitted. The form is being submit **after** your `onsubmit` handler is executed. Your JavaScript code will run, and your form will be sent.

By returning `false` in your function, you can abort submission. If you want the form to be submitted, I suggest to return `true`, just to make sure.

---

### Edit

Alright, so you're doing the following:

1. User enters zip code
2. Button is clicked, so you change the iframe's src
3. Form is submit
4. Handled with PHP

When you submit a form, a page refresh is required. PHP runs server-side, so you need a new request for PHP to run (unless you use AJAX, but that's another story). You have to change the iframe's URL when the page is laoded again. You don't need JavaScript at all.

```
<form action="#" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="zipcode" placeholder="12345" value="<?php echo $_POST['zipcode']; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!" />
</form>

<?php
// Are we dealing with a POST request?
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $zip = $_POST['zipcode'];
    $file = 'record.txt';

    // There's no guarantee we can open this file
    if($handle = fopen($file, 'a')) {
        $str = $zip . ',' . date('c') . ',' . "\r\n";

        fwrite($handle, $str);
        fclose($handle);
    }

    // Looks like everything went well. It's time to display the iframe!
    $url = 'http://www.example.com?zipCode=' + $zip;
    echo '<iframe src="' . $url . '"></iframe>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Please see the sample code. When I submit, the iframe content does not refresh.

Comment: Thank you so much and this works! I used AJAX to get the job done as well.